# Execute JAR and read the console output using InputStream - Java

Tags: java, logging, inputstream

I have a `myfile.jar` file which I'm executing through another Java program using ProcessBuilder and trying to read the console output of the jar using InputStream as follows:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "myfile.jar", "arg1");
Process p = pb.start();

InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader ins = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ins);

String line;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

p.waitFor();
p.destroy();
```

When I execute the above code, I'm not getting anything printed on the console. The `myfile.jar` was not developed by myself. But when I read through the code of `myfile.jar` it uses the `Logger` to print on the console using `ConsoleHandler`. I assume this may be the issue.

**EDIT**: When `java -jar myfile.jar arg1` is executed standalone on the console, it prints the output on the console.

This is driving me nuts for past 3 days. The direction to solve this problem would help me to learn more.

Comment: is `java -jar myfile.jar arg1` from command line working?

Comment: Yes, it prints the nice output on the console when executed standalone.

Comment: You need to process the error stream as well, you can use [ProcessBuilder#redirectErrorStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream()) while redirect the error stream through the input stream

Comment: By executing the `myfile.jar`, there will be a file generated. So using the above code, it generates the file successfully. Hence I don't think the `redirectErrorStream` is really required. But I'll give a try

Comment: @MadProgrammer The redirectErrorStream worked like a charm. But I don't understand the logic here. Do you mind explaining here?

Comment: I was hoping for some error output, but, it's possible that Java (or your programming) is outputting via the stderr stream

Comment: @MadProgrammer, thanks for your answer. If you can add as an answer, I can mark it as answered.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, need your help on the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687838/java-pass-values-to-the-jar-using-outputstreamwriter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When processing an external process, you should not only consume/monitor the stdout, but also the stderr.

You could use a second reader to read the stderr stream from the process, but generally it's easier to combine the streams using [`ProcessBuilder#redirectErrorStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream()), which redirect the stderr through the processes `InputStream`.

Sometimes a process will output to the stderr instead of the stdout.

Even if you're not using the output of these streams, it's always a good idea to read them as some processes can stall if the streams are not flushed.