# Java: Pass values to the jar using OutputStreamWriter

Tags: java, outputstream

I'm trying to execute `myfile.jar` using another java program which as follows. When the `myfile.jar` is executed standalone in console, it will as two questions:

1. Start the load process (y/n)?
2. Start the patch process (y/n)?

I will pass `y` to 1st and `n` to 2nd question. The same thing I'm trying to do using the following java program and it successfully passes answer to the 1st question, but waiting at the 2nd question.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "myfile.jar", "arg1");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process p = pb.start();

InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader ins = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ins);

String line = null;

out.write("y\n");
out.write("n\n");
out.flush();

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

out.close();
p.waitFor();
p.destroy();
```

**Note**: The `myfile.jar` uses `Scanner` to take the input from the user.

Comment: Does myfile.jar write end-of-line after the "Start the patch process (y/n)?"

Comment: @bedrin: It takes the input from the new line. I believe you are trying to ask that.

Comment: do you have the source code of myfile.jar? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: @bedrin, unfortunately I do not have an access to that code. As far as I know, the dev was telling me that it uses the Scanner to take input from user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I found the solution to my question. For future reference, the following is the final program that I've used to solve my problem:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "myfile.jar", "arg1");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

Process p = pb.start();

InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader ins = new InputStreamReader(in);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(ins);

String line = null;

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);

    if (line.contains("Start the load process (y/n)?")) {
        out.write("y");
        out.newLine();
        out.flush();
    }

    if (line.contains("Start the patch process (y/n)?")) {
        out.write("n");
        out.newLine();
        out.flush();
    }
}

out.close();
p.waitFor();
p.destroy();
```